# Getting AWS SNS Messages into Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, aws

I have a similar question to one already asked about SQS to Azure Service Bus - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650073/consume-aws-sqs-and-publish-to-azure-service-bus.  I want to get messages from AWS SNS (hosted by another party) into an Azure Service Bus and wondering about the best approach.

Ideally, I don't want to have to host an Azure Web App as the HTTP endpoint/middleware, but I'm not sure an Azure Logic App/Function exposed over HTTP would work without other resources also being needed.  I also have a preference not to deploy anything in AWS when the rest of my solution will be in Azure.

I'm still learning about Azure so may be missing something obvious. Any experience/advice for this scenario would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a one-time migration or a continuous flow from SQS to Service Bus?

Comment: Continuous flow, ongoing process.  We have a SaaS supplier that is AWS based, where we are building an Azure capability.

Comment: Hey @GRoberts - were you able to find a solution? I think I am going to create an azure functionas a middleware

Comment: Hey @Dmitry - that is exactly what I ended up doing too.  Slightly annoying, as it means we have to schedule the function to poll, rather than having it triggered, which limits the scaling possibilities.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is host a lambda function in AWS to forward the message.  Due to the small footprint, it shouldn't cost too much, but it's exactly what you said you didn't want to do.  I understand your reasons as well.